# Problem with sorting in custom child taxonomy archive page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I have this code:

```
<?php

$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;

$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );?>

<div
    class="gdlr-core-event-item-list gdlr-core-style-grid gdlr-core-item-pdlr gdlr-core-column-20  clearfix">

    <div class="gdlr-core-event-item-thumbnail">

        <a
            href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ); ?>">
            <?php $image_corsi = get_field('immagine', $term); ?>
            <img
                src="<?php echo $image_corsi['sizes']['corsi-img']; ?>"
                width="700" height="935" alt="" /></a>

    </div>

    <div class="gdlr-core-event-item-content-wrap">

        <h3 class="gdlr-core-event-item-title"><a
                href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
        </h3>

        <div class="gdlr-core-event-item-info-wrap"><span
                class="gdlr-core-event-item-info gdlr-core-type-time"></span><span
                class="gdlr-core-event-item-info gdlr-core-type-location">
                <div class="clear"></div><a
                    class="gdlr-core-excerpt-read-more gdlr-core-button gdlr-core-rectangle"
                    href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ); ?>"><?php pll_e('Scopri di più', 'trad-scopri'); ?></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<?php
}?>
```

The code works and is placed in a custom archive taxonomy child template. But what I would like to do is sort the list of posts by custom field (data) created with the ACF plugin. How should I do this starting from this code?
I am inexperienced and I am having a lot of effort.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

This example will use the get_posts function to load all the ‘**events**’ posts ordered by a custom field value of ‘**my_acf_field**’.

you can using like this, where I added '**my_acf_field**' you can place with your ACF field name.

```
<?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'event', // Post Type Name
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,    // '-1' display all post, if you write '2' 
                                          then display only 2 post.
    'meta_key'          => 'my_acf_field',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value', // get my_acf_field stored value
    'order'             => 'DESC'  // you can set your order type here!
));

if( $posts ): ?>
    
    <ul>
        
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        
        setup_postdata( $post )
        
        ?>

         /* write your code here */

        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> (date: <?php the_field('start_date'); ?>)</a>  
             /* 'start_date' is another field name of ACF */
        </li>
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    
    </ul>
    
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```